# Java - SonarQube, issue on 'Utility classes should not have public constructors' (squid:S1118) in singleton

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am performing static code analysis on old code using a SonarLint analysis. I cannot paste the code here but it is similar to:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public class SuperClass {

    private SuperClass() {
    }

    public static SuperClass getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.instance;
    }

    private static class InstanceHolder {
        public final static SuperClass instance = new SuperClass();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        //do something
    }

}
```

SonarQube (sonar-java: 4.2.1.6971), reports an issue on [S1118](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1118?layout=false).

Adding a private constructor to `InstanceHolder` has no solving effect here, since `SuperClass`is the only class that can create an instance of it due to its private modifier.

`SuperClass` can still create an instance, even with `ÌnstanceHolder` having a private constructor.

BTW: adding the constructor removes the sonar-issue, so I think the analyzer marked this as a rule violation because of the internal 'UtilityClass' without further investigation.

Is this a bug? Instead of a design flaw, this is an example of a thread-safe singleton.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your error message. Error message is stating that `InstanceHolder` doesn't need a private constructor (which is true), but in your code there is no private constructor in `InstanceHolder`.

Comment: ´Add a private constructor to hide the implicit public one.´ is what sonar states.  Adding the constructor has no effect. No one except the SuperClass can create an instance, SuperClass still can.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Sonar wants you to add a private constructor to `InstanceHolder`? I think that's a bug with sonar.

Comment: Yes, that's a bug or rather a limitation of the SonarQube analyzer. I mark those issues as `Resolve as won't fix` as a private constructor wouldn't make any difference

Comment: The issue is now addressed in https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2562

Answer (score -1):

Make your class final so that Instance creation can be avoided.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public final class SuperClass {

        private SuperClass() {
        }
    }
```